# How to install MySQL or MsSQL with a personal setup

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, installation, exe4j

I want to develop an external PC application using `Java` and `MsSQL/MySQL`. 
I want to share it with all people. But I have no idea about how to install `MS SQL` or `MySQL` automatically with my Application setup, without a normal manual database installation. 
Or is there any other way to develop such an app using "Java + any database server"?
Or is there any best way to success this process with Java?

Comment: Standalone applications shouldn't rely on a local database server. Try an embedded database system like SQLite or set up a hosted webserver.

Comment: @shmosel Thank you very much for you response. I have never tried SQLit  before. I'll research on it sir. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are programming in netbeans you need include the database within netbeans? Here is a guide on how to do this.

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql.html

Also here is a second guide on Packaging and Distributing Java Desktop Applications

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/javase-deploy.html

Comment: yes I'm using netbeans. I have never heard about this and thank you very much for your response sir.